# Sefardi Hilchot aveilut online

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, internet, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mourning-aveilus

Do we have any sefardi Halachic book (pdf format) in English dealing with Hilchot Aveilut Online? I need it a bit urgently to study it this Tisha b'Av.

Comment: In Hebrew, [On Your Way](http://mobile.tora.ws/) is bh a free mobile and web app with, for example, the entire Kitzur Yalkut Yosef. (Including hilchot avelut.)

Comment: In hebrew we have a lot of websites that provides it. I want it in english

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of Sephardic Halacha on [Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mourning).

Comment: I wont deny the fact that there is but they cite random opinions. And a lot of times, I came across a lot of topics that does not cite even a single sefardic source. And that is why I want a book.